# Sentence with two 'than's in a row

Tags: sentence-patterns, doubled-words

I'm looking for a sentence with two 'than's in a row. I'm sure they exist but I just can't think of one!

Comment: _Than_ is restricted to the comparative construction (_This one is bigger than that one_), and while you can get two comparative constructions in one sentence if you shove hard, this does not result in any grammatical sequences of *_than than_. Getting several _that_'s in a row is simple, because _that_ has a number of uses; but there's only one _than_.

Comment: There are few words less interesting than than.

Comment: It turns out that *than* has two uses. In sentences like *Scarcely was the work completed than it was abandoned* is means *when*. Therefore, it should be possible to compose a sentence that will have two *than*s, one essentially following the other. Very unlikely to produce one that is easy to understand, though. One example could be *Scarcely was the work completed, and never earlier than, than it was abandoned*.

Comment: "Sentence is a longer word than than."

Comment: I have to close this as it is setting a precedent for asking "I'm looking for a sentence with the word *excavator* twice in a row", then asking "I'm looking for a sentence with five *for*s in a row, then asking "I'm looking for a sentence with ten *a*s in a row. The real question is, *why* are you looking for it. What could you possibly need it for.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely contrived, and most will probably consider it completely ungrammatical, but I thought of:

*David is more taller than Ben than than Sarah.*

Which is to say, the degree by which David is taller than Ben exceeds the degree by which David is taller than Sarah.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a better word than than to ask this question about?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/355506)

Comment: This is a sentence with two thans in a row as requested.